# How to deal with incorrect reviews

Tags: discussion

I was going through review of some questions that was voted for closing. [One of them](https://serverfault.com/review/close/125007) was marked as unclear what you are asking. I read the question, and to me it was perfectly clear what the OP was asking, and what the answer to that question was.

One might argue that the question was off-topic or that the OP had not done enough research before asking. But I did not consider it so clearly off-topic, that I would vote to close it. And since it was definitely not unclear what was being asked, I chose the keep open option.

Next I am told:

> STOP! Look and Listen.
>   This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass.

And the only option I am given then is to click `I understand`. But I disagree, I think the people who originally flagged that question as "unclear what you are asking" made a mistake, or did simply not put enough effort into understanding the question.

What do I do next? Do I simply ignore that this question was closed with an inappropriate reason? Or is there something else, I should be doing?

The question was: [What protocol do these segments use?](https://serverfault.com/questions/590245/what-protocol-do-these-segments-use)

Comment: The review audit questions are picked by an algorithm, which is to say that many of them are poor choices.  I recall there even being one or two we had to get removed from the audit list because the answer the audit expected was flat out wrong.  So don't sweat it.

Comment: It seems the search engine I used to find out if my question had been asked before has not performed any OCR on that other question. My search terms are in a screenshot in that other question, but are found nowhere else on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Closing this question is appropriate, though "unclear what you're asking" might not have been the best choice of close reason.

This is pretty obviously a homework question, not something a professional system administrator would typically deal with; as the comments show, we would just load it up into Wireshark and view any necessary information about the packets.

There's nothing you really need to do about this specific audit. Occasionally failing audits happens to everyone who reviews; I've even been known to fail them once or twice.

Comment: Had the question been presented to me with off-topic as the reason, I might have followed suit if I agreed with the more specific reason. Otherwise I would probably have skipped it because I think that is the right thing to do, if you aren't certain what answer should be given. But I still think keeping open is appropriate if the reason given for closing is clearly not applicable.

Comment: You could also have chosen to _close_ with a different reason than the one given in the review.

Comment: That I could have. But there wasn't another reason where I thought that it should definitely without doubt be closed for that reason.